# Rome: Total War Gold Editon failed to contact key server

Tags: steam, rome-total-war

I just bought Rome: Total War Gold Edition on Steam - however, when I try to play it, a message comes up and says `Failed to contact key server`.
Do I need to have the standard Rome game first?

Comment: Sounds more like servers dying under the load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend got the same problem It seems to be a server overload. Try again in a few hours.